# Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out after apt upgrade

Tags: dpkg, systemd, systemd-logind

When I run my regular

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove
```

I get

```
...
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.103.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
Failed to reload daemon: Connection reset by peer
Failed to get unit file state for clamav-freshclam.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to retrieve unit state: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
clamav-freshclam.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to retrieve unit state: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to start clamav-freshclam.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-freshclam, action "start" failed.
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--configure):
 installed clamav-freshclam package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:
 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.103.2+dfsg) | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package clamav (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 clamav-freshclam
 clamav
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and while that looks like [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241017/failed-to-activate-service-org-freedesktop-systemd1-timed-out), the answers there are not helpful:

```
$ busctl | grep systemd1
org.freedesktop.systemd1                - -               -                (activatable) -                           -       -
```

(after hard reboot, this line is not `(activatable)`.)

```
$ systemctl daemon-reexec
$ sudo kill 1
$ busctl | grep systemd1
org.freedesktop.systemd1                - -               -                (activatable) -                           -       -          
$ systemctl --version
systemd 246 (246.6-1ubuntu1.3)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid
```

So I can't restart it and the version is higher than 236 which had an issue.

How do I recover? In the current state, I can't logout or shutdown. I have to hard reset. And apt upgrade fails.

**System Information**

```
$ uname -a
Linux codex 5.8.0-49-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 24 14:45:45 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep -v "^#"
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal main
deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
deb [arch=amd64] https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/audacity/ubuntu focal main
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v "^#"
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy restricted universe multiverse main #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-updates main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-updates restricted universe multiverse main #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy universe
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-updates universe
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy multiverse
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-updates multiverse
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-security main restricted
deb-src http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-security restricted universe multiverse main #Added by software-properties
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-security universe
deb http://mirror.uchile.cl/ubuntu/ groovy-security multiverse
```

Apparently `clamav` is the culprit. Will poke them, too.

```
$ busctl | grep systemd1
org.freedesktop.systemd1                 1 systemd         root             :1.0          init.scope                  -       -          
$ sudo apt install clamav
...
Setting up clamav-base (0.103.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
uid=125(clamav) gid=134(clamav) groups=134(clamav)
Setting up clamav-freshclam (0.103.2+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.10.1) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/clamav-freshclam.service → /lib/systemd/system/clamav-freshclam.service.
Failed to reload daemon: Connection reset by peer
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on clamav-freshclam.service: No such file or directory
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to get unit file state for clamav-freshclam.service: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to retrieve unit state: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
clamav-freshclam.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Failed to retrieve unit state: Connection timed out
Failed to start clamav-freshclam.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status clamav-freshclam.service' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript clamav-freshclam, action "start" failed.
Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
dpkg: error processing package clamav-freshclam (--configure):
 installed clamav-freshclam package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of clamav:
 clamav depends on clamav-freshclam (>= 0.103.2+dfsg) | clamav-data; however:
  Package clamav-freshclam is not configured yet.
  Package clamav-data is not installed.
  Package clamav-freshclam which provides clamav-data is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package clamav (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for systemd (246.6-1ubuntu1.3) ...
Failed to reload daemon: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
...
$ busctl | grep systemd1
org.freedesktop.systemd1                 - -               -                (activatable) -                           -       -
```

This issue was [reported to ClamAV](https://bugzilla.clamav.net/show_bug.cgi?id=12760), too.

Comment: What OS do you have installed? It seems the `apt full-upgrade` has broken your system. This happens often when you have customized your system outside of the package manager, for example by installing and using third party packages. https://embeddedinventor.com/apt-upgrade-vs-full-upgrade-differences-explained-for-beginners/

Comment: Added system information. I did `sudo apt remove --purge clamav-base` as that's where the errors appeared but the system is broken for now until the next reboot at least :(

Comment: What is `systemctl status org.freedesktop.systemd1` telling you?

Comment: @paladin `Failed to get properties: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)`

Comment: Use `ps aux --sort=-%mem` look for high memory consuming processes and try to deactivate (and maybe disable) their daemon/service (`kill PSID`, `systemctl stop DAEMON/SERVICE-NAME` and `systemctl disable DAEMON/SERVICE-NAME`. All in regard to your system RAM size. Use `htop` to make sure your RAM is not 100% full. Use `systemctl restart systemd-logind`.

Comment: I can now upgrade the system after purging freshclam but somehow the issue is not all fixed. The latest kernel doesn't let me login.

Regarding memory, I have 32GB and also checked for free RAM during crashed systemd and there was plenty of RAM free, so no, I doubt it's RAM.

Comment: In my case, I was tring purge dbus and reinstalling it. Then I found dbus have unmet dependencies `fish` , then I purged fish and found systemd worked again. For people with same problem, purge and reinstall dbus could be a solution. Honestly I haven't figured out why and fish has been uninstalled.